# TypeScript: Cant assign a value to this.x in the class constructor

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface ClassInterface {
    canvasWidth: number;
    canvasHeight: number;
};

class Nodes<ClassInterface>  {
    constructor(canvasWidth: number, canvasHeight: number) {
        console.log(canvasWidth); // 820
        console.log(canvasHeight); // 620
        this.canvasWidth = canvasWidth;
//               ^ Error when i try to assign it to this.
        this.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;
//               ^ Error when i try to assign it to this.
    }
    update(tick) {
    }
    draw(ctx) {
    }
}

export { Nodes };
```

Does the class or constructor need an interface, how is `this` declared?

I'm invoking the class with

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Nodes } from './nodes';
import './scss/App.scss';

const App = () => {
  const canvasWidth = 820; //<------- Set canvasWidth
  const canvasHeight = 620; //<------- Set canvasHeight
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  if (canvasRef.current) {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (ctx) {
      canvas.width = canvasWidth;
      canvas.height = canvasHeight;
      const nodes = new Nodes(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); //<--- Pass in both
      let now = 0;
      const tickLoop = (epoch: number) => {
        const tick = epoch - now;
        now = epoch;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        nodes.update(tick);
        nodes.draw(ctx);
        requestAnimationFrame(tickLoop);
      };
      requestAnimationFrame(tickLoop);
    }
  }
  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={canvasWidth}
      height={canvasHeight}
    >
    </canvas>
  );
};

export { App };
```

the error I get is

```
Property 'canvasWidth' does not exist on type 'Nodes<ClassInterface>'
```

Comment: The `interface ClassInterface` is not related to the `ClassInterface` in `class Nodes<ClassInterface>` at all. It could've been `Nodes<T>` just as well. Could you explain a bit more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to pass `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` to `class Nodes` and then be able to access them in the constructor via `this.canvasWidth` and `this.canvasHeight', the new eror with your suggestion is `Property 'canvasWidth' does not exist on type 'Nodes<T>'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Did you mean `class Nodes implements ClassInterface`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Nodes {
  canvasWidth: number; // <=== declare them here not in an interface
  canvasHeight: number; // <=== declare them here not in an interface
  constructor(canvasWidth: number, canvasHeight: number) {
    this.canvasWidth = width;
    this.canvasHeight = height;
  }
  update(tick) {
      // update any this.x or any object you import
  }
  draw(ctx) {
      // draw somthing on the page
  }
}

export { Nodes };
```